# Display table-row div to take "rest" with overflow in FF

Tags: css, html

I have a stacked div layout that displays the following sections implemented as `display: table-row`

- Header
- Section 1
- Section 2
- Footer

The sections are wrapped inside a wrapper div with `display: table`.

Section 2 should take the remaining space and render it's contents inside this section. Overflowing content in this section should scroll as is overflows.

Here's a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/naaQb/) that shows more or less what it should do but it works only in Chrome. In IE11/FF the overflow doesn't work and the content pushes the footer out of the viewport.

Is this an issue with my implementation or a general issue in browsers other than Chrome?

Comment: you need to give some height @ data_section_wrapper css .. refer this might help -- https://channel9.msdn.com/Forums/TechOff/74756-FireFox-div-100-height-bug

Comment: The `#data_section_wrapper` has an height of 100%. An that's what I'd like to achieve. It should take the remaining space. Or is 100% not some height? But setting a fixed height will make the content scroll at least. But that's not what I'd like to achieve as I can not predict the height and it should take the the remaining as it does in Chrome. :)

Answer (score 0):

Adding the margin -20px @data_section will do the trick .. i know its kind of hack and my best explanation is css behavior are define by respected browser engines.  This works in chrome and FF browser.

```
#data_section {
/*Section 2*/
position: relative;
background: red;
height: inherit;
overflow: auto;
margin-bottom: -20px;
}
```

[Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/naaQb/1/)